# firebase init error. (node:82729) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cli

When I init firebase on my react app,
I got the theme error after I passed some firebase asking.

under following on detail.

```
What language would you like to use to write Cloud Functions? (Use arrow keys)

❯ JavaScript
  TypeScript (node:82729) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error
    at new FirebaseError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/error.js:9:18)
    at module.exports (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/responseToError.js:38:12)
    at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/api.js:39:35)
    at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
(node:82729) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:82729) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I didn't have such a error when I used to create some react app. but,I got this error today.I think I will get this error on my node.js. but I don't know how I fix my node.js .

I am beginner for node.js and firebase.
How should I fix this error?

I tried to fix some solution I found on Internet. following

I did reinstall node.js v12.18.3 from v10.12.3 .Also, I reinstall firebase-tools on my mac. I tried to reinstall firebase on my react app before  firebase init.

Also, I ignored this error and then complete initializing firebase. but When I did firebase deploy , I couldn't do that .Instead of, I got this error on my command line.

`Error: HTTP Error: 404, Method not found.`

Now, I can't solve this error.
If you have any ideas, please help and advise me.
Thank you for reading!

06/ 09 / 2020 added my firebase.json and react package.json.
here is firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

here is package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-bot",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase": "^7.19.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**already installed packages.**

firebase-tools@8.10.0

firebase@7.19.1

node.js v12.18.3

macOS10.15.6

bug picture
[image]

and if I did `firebase deploy` I got this error.
[image]

I tried to replace "$RESOURCE_DIR" with %RESOURCE_DIR% .I got different error.
[image]

Comment: Could you please share your code? The error normally appears when an unhandled promise rejection have to be handled using  .catch() on the promise to handle the rejection. Could you please update the firebase-tools to the latest version and run firebase login --reauth ? Please let me know if it works.

Comment: Also please share your firebase.json file in the case the previous doesn't work.

Comment: @NibrassH Thank you for replying.  once I deleted all project. firest , I did update firebase-tools for  firebase-tools@8.10.0. and then I reinstalled firebase@7.19.1 on my react app. and I did  firebase login --reauth. However, I got the same error...

Comment: @NibrassH Also, I placed my firebase.json and package.json here. Please check. If you find any problems, please advise me and I want to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for sharing all the above information. I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First update the firebase-tools:

```
npm install -g  firebase-tools
```

After seeing your screenshot, I was able to see the error when deploying the function.

Try to replace $RESOURCE_DIR with %RESOURCE_DIR% in your `firebase.json` file.

**Multi platform solution**

Linux

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
]
```

PowerShell

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix $Env:RESOURCE_DIR run lint"
]
```

Cmd.exe

```
"predeploy": [
"npm --prefix %RESOURCE_DIR% run lint"
]
```

The previous was discussed in the following [Github Issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/822#issuecomment-406754186). Please have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I tried to replace $RESOURCE_DIR with %RESOURCE_DIR% in my firebase.json. but I got a different error ...Please check my question. I put my error picture. Also, I checked your github discussing. I am Mac user(OS10.15.6) not windows. This solution is same ?

Comment: Is this error caused by firebase recognizing my development environment as windows? When I was selecting language (Js or Ts), I got the error "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" . This error is firebase recognizing as windows, too ? How do you think ? I'm sorry to continue asking questions. I expect your reply.

Comment: Could you please try with the following code? {
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run build"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: The error which you are getting now is because you are in Mac and probably the previous syntax wasn't for MAC. If my previous comment doesn't work for you, could you please try the following one: {
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  }
}

Comment: Thank you for replying ! Finally , I found direct problem for this error. It' my firebase version . My local firebase version(v6. ~ ) was older than my global firebase version. If I upgrade firebase and do ```npm install -g  firebase-tools ``` on command, I could not upgrade my local firebase.  So, I deleted my local firebase once and connected global pass on local bin. Finally, Everything is working !! Thanks to your advice , I solved this error. If I didn't get your advice , I couldn't find the fix point. you are God!   If you come to Japan, I will give you sushi and tempura !! thank you !

Comment: haha, no problem, glad to help :D, really appreciated your comments haha :D